# Many-to-many mapping entities in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, many-to-many

I have SQL Server tables as follows:

```
create table TableA (
id int primary key identity,
name varchar(16) not null
)
create table TableB (
id int primary key identity,
data varchar(max) not null
)
create table TableAtoB (
tablea_id int not null foreign key references TableA(id),
tableb_id int not null foreign key references TableB(id),
primary key nonclustered (tablea_id, tableb_id)
)
create unique index idxID on TableAtoB(tableb_id, tablea_id)
```

and mappings in C# as follows:

```
[Table]
public class TableA
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

[Table]
public class TableB
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string data { get; set; }
}

[Table]
public class TableAtoB
{
    [Column]
    public int tablea_id { get; set; }
    internal EntityRef<TableA> _tablea;
    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, OtherKey = "ID", ThisKey = "tablea_id", Storage = "_tablea")]
    public TableA tablea
    {
        get { return _tablea.Entity; }
        internal set { _tablea.Entity = value; }
    }
    [Column]
    public int tableb_id { get; set; }
    internal EntityRef<TableB> _tableb;
    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, OtherKey = "ID", ThisKey = "tableb_id", Storage = "_tableb")]
    public TableB tableb
    {
        get { return _tableb.Entity; }
        internal set { _tableb.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

However, I get **System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid association mapping for member 'TableAtoB.tablea'. 'TableAtoB' is not an entity.** Are my entity mappings not correct?

I cannot change the table schema.

Comment: Couple of thoughts: Could it be that `primary key nonclustered (tablea_id, tableb_id)` needs representing in your `TableAToB` class? Does the case of `ID` matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the ColumnAttribute.IsPrimaryKey property:

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
public int tablea_id { get; set; }
...
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
public int tableb_id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try auto-generating the tables using the designer and see what is generated. There are some additional constructor and event listeners for EntityRef's which you appear to be missing. Also, It appears that neither of your end tables have the typical reference to the many to many table as you will find in the designers.

Also, you may want to take a look at the implementation in PLINQO http://www.codesmithtools.com/plinqo as they were able to implement a code generated method of hiding the middle (TableAtoB) table and give a more object oriented code spit similar to how EF handles Many to Many relationships.